# How to change element name on Page load with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to know how i can change the name of a element. I have the id of that element say it is `"tester"` 
Ok the on page load problem could be solved this way.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 });
```

but how can i change the name of a element like this?

```
<div id="tester" name="fun">
</div>
```

what i want as result

```
<div id="tester" name="tester">
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#tester").attr("name","tester");
```